# Connection to SQL server fails when asp.net app is published to IIS

Tags: asp.net

I currently use the following connection string for my database during development. The database is installed locally on my machine and on the same machine as iis. In my web.conf file

```
<add key="DatabaseConnectionString"   
     value="Data Source=(localdb)\MyDb;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;App=EntityFramework;" />
```

Now the above works fine during development. However when I publish my app to IIS the first attempt to connect to the db just hangs

```
   DbContext dbcontext = new DbContext(Constant.DatabaseConnectionString);
   List<string> listIds = dbcontext.Messages.Select(x => x.TaskId).Distinct().ToList(); //Hangs here
```

Any suggestions if I should be doing something differently to the connection string before publishing the  app ?

Comment: Fails with what error? In any case, that connection string is for [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15), an embedded database, that shouldn't be used in production. With an embedded database, the application itself, in this case IIS, runs the database.

Comment: Does the database even exist?

Comment: Yes the database exists and the error is that it just hangs. How do I embed a database in iis ?

Comment: It hangs where? Have you tried debugging the application? Have you checked the logs? If you don't have any logging, add logging code to see what's going on. ` How do I embed a database in iis` you already did, that's the point. Also, you **won't be using it in production**, so why not use SQL Server Express? LocalDB is a feature on top of SQL Server Express, so you have to install it one way or another

Comment: Chek [Configure IIS to use LocalDB](https://codemegeek.com/2018/05/13/configure-iis-to-us-localdb/) if you want, but remember - you can just as easily connect to SQL Server Express, both for development and production.